# Roots of Taylor Polynomials of analytic function with finite radius of convergence

Tags: reference-request

In 1914 Jentzsch proved that if 
$$
g(z)=1+a_1z+\ldots+a_nz^n+\ldots
$$ 
has the unit circle as circle of convergence then every point of this circle is a cluster-point of zeros of partial sums
$$
s_n(z)=1+a_1z+\ldots+a_nz^n.
$$
I was wodering if you could point me out an alternative English written reference for
*Untersuchungen zur Theorie der Folgen analytischer Functionen. Inaud.-diss., Berlin*
where the proof of this theorem is presented in details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generalization is proved, in English, in detail, in Hans-Peter Blatt, Simon Blatt, and Wolfgang Luh, On a generalization of Jentzsch's theorem, J. Approx. Theory 159 (2009), no. 1, 26–38, MR2533389 (2010d:30004).

Comment: Hi Gerry thanks a lot for this reference.